# Convert Kubernetes labels.Selector to metav1.LabelSelector

Tags: go, kubernetes

There are two Go types for working with label selectors: the [labels.Selector](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/v0.29.1/pkg/labels/selector.go#L49) interface, and the [metav1.LabelSelector](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/v0.29.1/pkg/apis/meta/v1/types.go#L1213) struct.

It is easy to convert `metav1.LabelSelector` to `labels.Selector` using the `metav1.LabelSelectorAsSelector` function:

```golang
func LabelSelectorAsSelector(ps *LabelSelector) (labels.Selector, error) {
```

How to do the reverse translation, i.e. convert `labels.Selector` to `metav1.LabelSelector`?

**Use-case**:

I have a function which receives a `labels.Selector`, which internally has to call another function that receives a `metav1.LabelSelector`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a better way, I found a two-step process which seems to work so far.

1. Stringify `labels.Selector` using `labels.Selector.String()`
2. Parse the string into a `metav1.LabelSelector` using `metav1.ParseToLabelSelector(string)`

**Example**:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    . "github.com/onsi/ginkgo/v2"
    . "github.com/onsi/gomega"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/labels"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/selection"
)

var _ = Describe("Label Selector", func() {
    const expectedLabelSelectorStr = "active,mode in (card,cash),service=payment"

    It("labels.Selector to metav1.LabelSelector", func() {
        r1, err := labels.NewRequirement("service", selection.Equals, []string{"payment"})
        Expect(err).ToNot(HaveOccurred())

        r2, err := labels.NewRequirement("active", selection.Exists, nil)
        Expect(err).ToNot(HaveOccurred())

        r3, err := labels.NewRequirement("mode", selection.In, []string{"cash", "card"})
        Expect(err).ToNot(HaveOccurred())

        selector := labels.NewSelector()
        selector = selector.Add(*r1, *r2, *r3)

        labelSelectorStr := selector.String()
        fmt.Println(labelSelectorStr)
        Expect(labelSelectorStr).To(Equal(expectedLabelSelectorStr))

        labelSelector, err := metav1.ParseToLabelSelector(labelSelectorStr)
        Expect(err).ToNot(HaveOccurred())
        Expect(metav1.FormatLabelSelector(labelSelector)).To(Equal(expectedLabelSelectorStr))
    })
})
```

I see that `metav1.ListOptions.LabelSelector` can be safely created from `labels.Selector.String()`. See [example in controller-runtime](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/blob/v0.17.0/pkg/cache/internal/selector.go).